# Calling .js file from HTML using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

this js is at index.html between `"<script type="text/javascript">"`

```
function callanular() {

        peticion_http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        peticion_http.onreadystatechange = showContent;

        peticion_http.open('GET', 'anular.js', true); 
        peticion_http.send(null);                       


        function showContent() {

            if(peticion_http.readyState == 4) {

                if(peticion_http.status == 200) {

                    document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML=peticion_http.responseText;

                }
                else
                    document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML="ERROR "+peticion_http.status;
            }
        }
    }
```

index.html HTML code I have, looking to show box on div with id=notice

```
<div id="notice"></div>
<input type="submit" value="RESTRICTED ACCESS" onclick="callanular()">
```

At the same folder I have anular.js created, *I want to show a simple box with a text*, in this case I only have an alert to know it's working.

```
window.onload = function() {
    return (alert("asdasdsa"));
}
```

Whatever I write I can only receive the literally code. e.g.

> > window.onload = function() {return (alert("asdasdsa")); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I solved it by using **Jquery** in **first** case, **AJAX** in **second** case.

> > **First Case**

Javascript code on index.html

```
function callanular() {

        $.getScript("anular.js", function(){
            //You can write an alert or something
            //In my case it wasn't necessary.
        });
    }
```

anular.js content

```
document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML = "<div id='nopul' onclick='getText()'>YOU SHOULDN`T PRESS THIS BUTTON</div><br>";
```

Back to index.html where I got:

```
<div id="notice"></div> //here anular.js is going to show the div box
<input type="submit" value="RESTRICTED ACCESS" onclick="callanular()">
```

At that point it was working fine as I wanted. So I added AJAX to get text from txt file simply doing a call to

> XMLHTTPRequest();
>
> peticion_http.open('GET', 'text.txt', true);

-

> > **Second Case**
> >     anular.js file

```
<div id='nopulses' onclick='getTexto()'>YOU SHOULDN`T PRESS THIS BUTTON</div><br>
```

index.html javascript code

```
        peticion_http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        peticion_http.onreadystatechange = showContent;

        peticion_http.open('GET', 'anular.js', true);  
        peticion_http.send(null);                       

        function muestraContenido() {

            if(peticion_http.readyState == 4) {

                if(peticion_http.status == 200) {

                    document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML=peticion_http.responseText;

                }
                else
                    document.getElementById("notice").innerHTML="ERROR 404 Not Found "+peticion_http.status;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the imported code in a script tag. Adding it to document body in a doc will not work. See answers here 
[Is it possible to load new Javascript files with AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031660/is-it-possible-to-load-new-javascript-files-with-ajax)