# How to remove script when button is clicked.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to remove  "js/sample.js"  file  from my html page when I click this `p` tag:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<style>
p { color:red; margin:5px; cursor:pointer; }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/sample.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<p>First Paragraph</p>
 <p>Second Paragraph</p>
 <p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>

<script>
$("p").click(function () {
$(' ').removeattr('src');

 });
 </script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish here?  You can't really "unload" script that's already been evaluated.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591685/how-can-i-dynamically-unload-a-javascript-file

Answer (score 5):

dear friend try the following code it will work for you

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script id="script1" src="js/sample.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {

        $("p").click(function () {
            $('script1').att('src').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the script tag with

`$('script[src="js/sample.js"]').remove();`

however, once the script has executed, simply removing that tag will not 'undo' the script. You need to actually destroy whatever variables/methods your sample.js script has created.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: @Racheet delete doesn't work for variable which is not instanciate as property of window global object

Comment: sorry, I used destroy when I probably should have said delete. How you go about this specifically depends on the content of sample.js itself.