# Javascript functions still remain after loading another partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, partial-views, event-listener

let's suppose the browser rendered following page

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div id="partialContainer">
<script>
function saveItems(){
    /* do somthing*/
}
</script>
<input type="button" id="btnTest" name="btnTest" value="Test" onclick="saveItems()"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

after an AJAX call and change the "partialContainer" content using

```
$("#partialContainer").html(returnedMarkup)
```

saveItems function still remains in page and can get executed 
how can remove this function when  markup get replaced to avoid name colissioning

Comment: you can disable or remove input button on click of which you are calling this function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically unload a javascript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591685/how-can-i-dynamically-unload-a-javascript-file)

Comment: @JamesThorpe  each partial may have it own script(s) by itself
witch doesn't referenced to a js file

Comment: @HosseinSalmanian It's pretty irrelevant whether a `<script>` tag has script within itself or is including an external file - once the file is loaded and executed, it may as well have been inline, ie the answers are more or less the same whether you have inline script or external files.

Comment: *How* does it get executed? If you need to change page functionality at the UI level then do it at the UI level rather than mucking with underlying functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`var saveItems = function () {}`

After your Ajax, assign some other value to it, preferably the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `saveItems` to `undefined`

```
   $("#partialContainer").html(returnedMarkup);
    if (!!saveItems && $.isFunction(saveItems)) saveItems = void 0;
```

Comment: i want to remove each function used in a dome element witch is replaced

Answer (score 0):

On your ajax success callback function, just do:

```
$("#btnTest").prop( "onclick", null );
```

Be aware that `$.removeAttr('onclick')` will fail in ie 6-8, so `.prop()` is better.

Comment: the main problem is that btnTest already removed from DOM but the function still remains and may cause function colissioning

Comment: Oh, i see. Did you try: " delete saveItems; " ?

Answer (score 0):

You could put your function in an object literal:

```
var obj = { saveItems: function() { } }
```

and delete it after the ajax

```
delete obj.saveItems
```